# How do I create an variable alias in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I'm new to Nim, so this might be an obtuse question, but how does one create a short-hand alias variable for the purpose of simplifying code?

For instance:

```
import sdl2
import sdl2.gfx

type
  Vector[T] = object
    x, y: T

  Ball = object
    pos: Vector[float]

  Game = ref object
    renderer: RendererPtr
    ball: array[10, Ball]

proc render(game: Game) =
  # ...

  # Render the balls
  for ix in low(game.ball)..high(game.ball):
    var ball : ref Ball = game.ball[ix]
    game.renderer.filledCircleRGBA(
        int16(game.renderer.ball[ix].pos.x),
        int16(game.renderer.ball[ix].pos.y),
        10, 100, 100, 100, 255)

  # ...
```

Instead of that last part, I'd like to use a shorter alias to access the ball position:

```
  # Update the ball positions
  for ix in low(game.ball)..high(game.ball):
    ??? pos = game.ball[ix].pos
    game.renderer.filledCircleRGBA(
        int16(pos.x),
        int16(pos.y),
        10, 100, 100, 100, 255)
```

However, if I use a `var` in place of `???`, then I seem to create a copy in `pos`, which then means the original isn't updated.  A `ref` isn't allowed, and `let` won't let me mutate it.

This seems a natural thing to want to do, so I'd be surprised if Nim doesn't let you do it, I just can't see anything in the manuals or tutorials.

[later] Well, apart from "abusing" `ptr` to achieve this, but I had thought that use of `ptr` is discouraged except for C API interoperability.

What I'm hoping for is something like Lisp/Haskell's `let*` construct...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another solution, maybe more Nim-like, would be to use a template. Templates in Nim are just a simple substitution at the AST level. So if you create a couple templates like this:

```
template posx(index: untyped): untyped = game.ball[index].pos.x.int16
template posy(index: untyped): untyped = game.ball[index].pos.y.int16
```

You can now replace your code with:

```
proc render(game: Game) =
  # Render the balls
  for ix in low(game.ball)..high(game.ball):
    var ball : ref Ball = game.ball[ix]
    game.renderer.filledCircleRGBA(
      posx(ix),
      posy(ix),
      10, 100, 100, 100, 255)
```

This will get converted to your original code on compile-time and not carry any overhead. It will also maintain the same type-safety of the original code.

Of course if this is something you find yourself doing often you can create a template to create the templates:

```
template alias(newName: untyped, call: untyped) =
  template newName(): untyped = call
```

This can then be used like this in your code:

```
proc render(game: Game) =
  # Render the balls
  for ix in low(game.ball)..high(game.ball):
    var ball : ref Ball = game.ball[ix]
    alias(posx, game.ball[ballIndex].pos.x.int16)
    alias(posy, game.ball[ballIndex].pos.y.int16)
    game.renderer.filledCircleRGBA(
      posx(ix),
      posy(ix),
      10, 100, 100, 100, 255)
```

As you can see that solution is only really useful if you use it multiple times. Also note that since the alias template is expanded within the for loop the created templates will be scoped in there as well and can therefore share a name just fine.

Of course what might be more normal in a game setting is to use a more object oriented approach (one of the few cases where OO really makes sense IMHO, but that's another discussion). If you crate a procedure for the ball type you can annotate it with the `{.this: self.}` pragma to save on some typing:

```
type
  A = object
    x: int

{.this: self.}
proc testproc(self: A) =
  echo x # Here we can acces x without doing self.x

var t = A(x: 10)
t.testproc()
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like using `template ball(): untyped = game.ball[ix]` works inside a loop over ix, but can you confirm that's safe in general?

Comment: Yes that should be generally safe. Putting it in the loop means that it is scoped within the loop. The template won't be visible anywhere outside the loop.

Comment: To add to that, the reason why using `ix` within the template works is because it returns untyped. This means that the template doesn't check that what it returns are actually valid types and such, it just pastes the AST in directly.

Answer (score 2):

There are [rules to creating a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584797/172690) so you would likely need to use an unsafe pointer into the memory held by the `Game` variable like this:

```
type
  Vector[T] = object
    x, y: T

  RendererPtr = ref object
    dummy: int

  Ball = object
    pos: Vector[float]

  Game = ref object
    renderer: RendererPtr
    ball: array[10, Ball]

proc filledCircleRGBA(renderer: RendererPtr, x, y: int16,
    a, b, c, d, e: int) =
  discard

proc render(game: Game) =
  # Render the balls
  for ix in low(game.ball)..high(game.ball):
    let ball: ptr Ball = addr game.ball[ix]
    game.renderer.filledCircleRGBA(
        int16(ball.pos.x), int16(ball.pos.y),
        10, 100, 100, 100, 255)
```

Note that the `let` only applies to the local `ball` alias, you can still mutate whatever it is pointing at. Another way to reduce typing might be to write a wrapper around `filledCircleRGBA` which accepts a `Game` and the index to the `Ball` you want to render:

```
proc filledCircleRGBA(renderer: RendererPtr, x, y: int16,
    a, b, c, d, e: int) =
  discard

proc filledCircleRGBA(game: Game, ballIndex: int,
    a, b, c, d, e: int) =
  filledCircleRGBA(game.renderer,
    game.ball[ballIndex].pos.x.int16,
    game.ball[ballIndex].pos.y.int16,
    a, b, c, d, e)

proc render(game: Game) =
  # Render the balls
  for ix in low(game.ball)..high(game.ball):
    game.filledCircleRGBA(ix, 10, 100, 100, 100, 255)
```

Depending on your performance needs you could [inline](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-procedural-type) that wrapper `proc` or turn it into a [template](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#templates) guaranteeing no proc call overhead.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a common Nim idiom? I considered this trick but decided it might be an abuse of ptr, which seems to be intended for use mainly as a C-interoperability back door.

Comment: I'm not sure, you could try asking on the [Nim forums](https://forum.nim-lang.org) or [any of the chat channels](https://nim-lang.org/community.html) the language developers seem to favour. Pointers aren't going away though, since that's one way of sharing memory between threads and/or language boundaries.

Comment: The answer on IRC seems to be "avoid the ptr solution", but that it might be made safe with a macro.

Comment: I've not yet watched it, but a macro solution is outlined here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EC9zCXlvY2k